# Confusion about vectors

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, insert

I would love to know what the code below means

I just want to know how it works tbh.

```
vector<int> lotteryNumVect(10); // I do not understand this part.

int lotteryNumArray[5] = {4, 13, 14, 24, 34}; // I understand this part.

lotteryNumVect.insert(lotteryNumVect.begin(), lotteryNumArray,
                      lotteryNumArray + 3); // I do not understand this part.

cout << lotteryNumVect.at(2) << endl; // I understand this part.
```

Comment: We love that you're here and this is not a working example.

Comment: `vector <int> lotteryNumVect(10);` creates a vector of `int` with 10 default constructed `int`s in it.

Comment: @nicomp what do you mean?

Comment: Your code was filled with `*` characters that made it invalid but it's better now.

Comment: Thanks @Ted Lyngmo

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo I tried to make some of the code bold and some italic for easier reading in the text editor but it didn't work :/

Comment: sorry @Alexander Zhang I'll try better next time.

Comment: markdown isn't supposed to work inside code fences. system automatically highlights them according to the detected language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This statement

```
vector <int> lotteryNumVect(10);
```

declares a vector with 10 elements initialized by zeroes.

That is there is used the constructor

```
explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

> 3 Effects: Constructs a vector with n default-inserted elements using
>   the specified allocator.

The second parameter of the constructor have a default argument so you may call the constructor specifying only the number of elements to be created in a vector.

This statements

```
lotteryNumVect.insert(lotteryNumVect.begin(), lotteryNumArray,
                      lotteryNumArray + 3);
```

inserts in the beginning of the vector 3 elements from the array.

So as a result the vector will look like

```
4, 13, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: thank you I liked your post but it wont publicly display it since i have a reputation lower than 15.

Comment: @Zav You are still able to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @Zav No problem.:)

Comment: Oh i understand it now thanks for the help really appreciate it :)

Comment: If you deem it as the best answer click on the check icon. It will mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: @Meraj al Maksud thanks.

Comment: My first time using stackoverflow Im just a 12 year old in my bedroom lol

Answer (score 5):

#### Explanation

1. Statement `vector <int> lotteryNumVect(10);`:

   This is an example of using constructor.
   According to [cplusplus](https://cplusplus.com/):

   > default (1) : `explicit vector (const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`
   >
   > fill (2) : `explicit vector (size_type n, const value_type& val = value_type(), const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`
   >
   > range (3) : `template <class InputIterator> vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());`
   >
   > copy (4) : `vector (const vector& x);`

   So, `vector <int> lotteryNumVect(10);` initializes the vector with ten zeros (see (1) above). `vector <int> lotteryNumVect(5, 2);` would initialize the vector with five twos (see (2) above).
   You can check the example [here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) to understand better.
2. Statement `lotteryNumVect.insert(lotteryNumVect.begin(), lotteryNumArray, lotteryNumArray + 3);`:

   This actually insertion via iterators. Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) out:

   > single element (1) : `iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);`
   >
   > fill (2) : `void insert (iterator position, size_type n, const value_type& val);`
   >
   > range (3) : `template <class InputIterator>
   >   void insert (iterator position, InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`

   The term `lotteryNumVect.begin()` actually points the first element of `lotteryNumVect` (see [vector::begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/)). Whereas `lotteryNumArray` and `lotteryNumArray+3` respectively points the first and the third elements of the `lotteryNumArray` array.
   So, basically `lotteryNumVect.insert(lotteryNumVect.begin(), lotteryNumArray, lotteryNumArray + 3);` inserts the first three elements of the `lotteryNumArray` to the beginning of the vector `lotteryNumVect`.

---

#### Further reading on std::vector

- [cpluscplus](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)
- [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)
- [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/)

#### How to navigate on cplusplus:

- Header: `cplusplus.com/reference/<type header name here>`
  Example: `cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/`
- Function/Container/Keyword: 
  `cplusplus.com/reference/<the header which contains it>/<function/container/keyword name>`
  Example: `cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/`
- Member function/variable:
  `cplusplus.com/reference/<the header which contains it>/<function/container/keyword name>/<member variable/function name>/`
  Example: `cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/`

Alternatively, you could [Google](https://google.com/) it. At which, you will get all of three sites in your search result and perhaps far better outcome.

Comment: Thanks for the help Meraj al Maksud really appreciate it. I would put a check on your answer ,but it was not simple enough. But, your answer is definitely the best in-depth answer but is a bit confusing nontheless, good job :)

Comment: No @zav, my answer is basically the same. I just added some more info for further reading. I'm hopeful that it will come handy for you in future as it did for me.

Comment: ok @Meraj al Maksud :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's go through step by step

```
vector<int> lotteryNumVect(10);
```

- Create a vector of `int`s. Set the size to 10.

```
lotteryNumVect.insert(lotteryNumVect.begin(), // Place to insert stuff
                      lotteryNumArray,        // Pointer to start of thing to insert
                      lotteryNumArray + 3);   // Pointer to end of stuff to insert
```

- Insert the first 3 things in `lotteryNumArray` in `lotteryNumVect`

Comment: `Create a vector of ints. Set the size to 10.`. that's inaccurate, what is the value of the int?

Comment: It will create a vector of 10 ints, all set to 0

Comment: thanks for trying to help.